# Policy about retrieving statistical data from Facebook

Tags: statistics, policy

I'm evaluating the feasability of retrieving statistical data from Facebook pages related to famous persons, in order to provide this data to a customer that will display some kind of popularity ranking on it's site.

I read the Facebook Platform Policies and posts on this site but everything is aimed at developing an application that is somehow connected with facebook, without finding something describing the acceptable use of APIs to just gather statistical data and make some business with it.

Can anybody provide me with a hint relevant for this particular situation ?